# Measure pytest setup times

Tags: python, pytest

With `--durations=10`, [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/) shows the 10 slowest tests. I have many tests all of them run pretty fast, but test *creation* takes long here and there, especially in constructs like

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg", [
   create_test_params(1),
   create_test_params_alt(256),  # may take long?
   # ...
   # long list here
   #
])
def test_all():
    # ...
```

Is there a way to find the `n` slowest test *creation* times?